# How to get random object `Data` and only if `secret` is False?

Tags: django

```
class Data(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    secret = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How to get random object `Data` and only if `secret` is False?

views:

```
Data.objects.get(..)
```

Answer (score 2):

All of this functionality is included in the Django [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) documentation.

```
Data.objects.filter(secret=False).order_by('?')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import shuffle

[.....]
    datas = Data.objects.filter(secret=False)
    items = list(datas)
    shuffle(items)
[.....]
```